# Android setting text for multiple inflated textviews only works on last

Tags: android, textview, layout-inflater

I'm new to Android and am trying to make a simple checklist app. I am testing adding textviews dynamically to the activity using an xml template for the textview. The problem is when I try to inflate more than one view it creates the textviews but only sets the text to the last view created.

Here is the code in the activity:

```
    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.main_linear_layout);

    TextView textView1 = (TextView)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.textview_template, linearLayout).findViewById(R.id.textview_template);
    TextView textView2 = (TextView)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.textview_template, linearLayout).findViewById(R.id.textview_template);
    TextView textView3 = (TextView)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.textview_template, linearLayout).findViewById(R.id.textview_template);

    textView1.setText("Take out trash.");
    textView2.setText("Wash windows.");
    textView3.setText("Why won't you work?");
```

Here is the main layout I am trying to insert the textviews into:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/main_linear_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="#EEEEEE"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF">
        <EditText android:id="@+id/new_task_text_edit"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/text_edit_hint"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button_add"
            android:onClick="addTask"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="4dp">

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the template code for the textview (textview_template.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textview_template"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="6dp"
        android:paddingBottom="6dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/item_box" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is what is showing:

[image]

I've tried setting the text after each inflate but before the next inflate but the results are the same. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually all your `textView1`,`textView2`,`textView3` are pointing to the same UI, coz you are inflating with the same id and you are searching immediately.

Id's must be different, and for such thing that you are coding better use `recyclerview` and adapter for it, coz above coding can be better.

Comment: Just say a tutorial for that on Google's website, so I'll check it out. Thank you.

Comment: you can see this [here](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html) , as a sample )

Answer (score 1):

textview_template.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/textview_template"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="6dp"
        android:paddingBottom="6dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/item_box"
 />
```

I don't know where your `main_linear_layout` id is but, activity code should be like this.

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.main_linear_layout);
 TextView textView1 = (TextView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.textview_template, null);
 TextView textView2 = (TextView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.textview_template, null);
 TextView textView3 = (TextView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.textview_template, null);

textView1.setText("Take out trash.");
textView2.setText("Wash windows.");
textView3.setText("Why won't you work?");
linearLayout.addView(textView1);
linearLayout.addView(textView2);
linearLayout.addView(textView3);
```

Comment: I did it this way initially but Android Studio gives a compile time error saying it can't parse the textview_template.xml file if the TextView is not nested in a layout of some sort.

Comment: you can do it your way it is not important, the important thing, while inflating remove findById, and dont pass linearlayout argument @Qwurticus